# type error and decidability - Compiler

Tags: types, compiler-construction, compiler-errors

Modern compilers throw out type errors for programs that fails to compile. What is "type error"?

And also what does decidability mean for type system?

Answer (score 1):

"Type error" can be one of two types of error: compile time or run time. The compiler checks the type of error at compile(static) and runtime(Dynamic) depending on which language you are using. C/C++ is static-typed language while pearl/PHP is a dynamic type checking language.

Basically type error is a syntax error where the compiler checks for code safety based on the syntax rules of a particular language. If the code doesn't match the syntax rules then compiler throws an error.

Type system is a mathematical model for checking the safety of source code. It contains certain rules for checking errors.

In general, decidability means Boolean answer yes or no. In a type system, the compiler checks for a particular sentence or part of a sentence in their mathematical model, mathematical model checks to see if this type of syntax formation is possible in machine or not.

So based on rules in mathematical model it has to decide weather the input will fit in the model or not. If not it will give an error, this is called decidability.